# Obfuscation and/or antivirus hiding of a batch file using SET. Would it work?

Tags: batch-file, command, dos, obfuscation

Hullo, I was just wondering whether a plain SET parameter could be used for obfuscations or any other protection from antivirus in Windows batch files.

I ask because I recently obtained the two "famous" batch virus scripts "PiFv," and "meLT." For study of course. They kept getting detected by antivirus, so I would disable it, study for a while and it would be deleted again. Lucky I have internet ;) Anyway, I tried to think of a way to hide the virus'.

I thought maybe because they are analyzed by string, merely a text change would help. So I used inconspicuous words like so

```
SET hello="@ Echo off"
%hello%
```

And so on. Unfortunately, Norton was clever enough to suss it (surprisingly) though it's status was lowered from "Infectious" to "Heuristic." I figured if it had gone from yes to maybe this could work.

Next I went on single letter changes making words, example, if I was to print "infect;"

```
set z=i
set h=n
set j=f
set x=e
set d=c
set q=t &echo %z%%h%%j%%x%%d%%q%
```

That has half worked. Although a lengthy process I think if a set alphabet was established then changed it might. Anyway, the half working. It is classed heuristic when off a USB, but not classed if off a floppy. Why? Also, do you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Half way through reading your question I thought the same as your second idea, splitting the words.

I can't test as different AV's will detect different things, but maybe try splitting them into half's instead of single letters, so it doesn't take as long to do.

```
set z=inf
set h=ect
echo %z%%h%
```

Another option would be to read in the complete commands from a text file

```
set /p z= <command.txt
echo %z%
```